# Shader Input Layout Invalid

Tags: c++, directx, shader

I am trying to add things to my working code, but it is returning an error [Invalid Arg] when calling **CreateInputLayout()**.

It works before I add the texture stuff, but fails when I add it.
The shader file compiled with no errors.
I think the way I made the layout is bad. Is this correct?

C++ Vertex structure:

```
struct VertexData{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
    XMFLOAT2 TexCoord;
};
```

C++ Layout:

```
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputLayout[]={
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 28, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    }; uint lSize=sizeof(inputLayout)/sizeof(inputLayout[0]);
```

Shader code:

```
    // Stuff from DX Tutorial 7
Texture2D txDiffuse : register( t0 );
SamplerState samLinear : register( s0 );

cbuffer ViewData : register(b0){
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}

struct VS_INPUT{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};
struct PS_INPUT{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

PS_INPUT VS(VS_INPUT input){
    PS_INPUT output=(PS_INPUT)0;

    output.pos=mul(input.pos, World);
    output.pos=mul(output.pos, View);
    output.pos=mul(output.pos, Projection);

    output.color = input.color;

    output.tex = input.tex;

    return output;
}

float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target {
    return input.color;
}
```

**Edit:**

After a bunch of twiddling with the shader code, I found that if I change the semantics of the...
**1st** position to:  **float4 pos : POSITION;**
**2nd** position to:  **float4 pos : SV_POSITION;**
...the input layout successfully creates.

I tried both without the SV_ [system value] prefix, but that also failed. I dont know why I cant have them be the same.

The [Semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Semantics_All1) seem a bit magical. Not sure if I should answer my own Q with this, or wait for someone smarter to answer better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structs do not match:

```
struct VertexData
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;  // float3 here
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
    XMFLOAT2 TexCoord;
};

struct VS_INPUT{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION; // float4 here
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};
```

For position  in 3D space I prefer to use float3. So, as your input layout:

```
"POSITION", 0, R32G32B32_FLOAT
```

About semantics magic:
Names in HLSL must match input layout names. For example:

Layout:

```
{ "POSITION", 0, .. }
```

Vertex Shader:

```
float4 pos : POSITION0;
```

The only exception is that pixel shader must always have `float4 pos : SV_POSITION` semantics for the input position of pixel (It is a one of the **S**ystem **V**alue semantics).

And as a bonus, some commonly used stuff I'd like to recommend:

- `int size = ARRYSIZE(inputayoutDesc);`
- use `D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT` instead of 12, 28, numbers as alignment offset.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Also, the mismatch floats is something I asked about before. People say its for aligning the data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889619/understanding-shader-programming

Answer (score 0):

Input semantics shouldn't be SV_POSITION if they are in your input vertices, they should be POSITION I think.

Also you declare this -

```
struct VS_INPUT{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
```

Shouldn't this be `float3 pos : POSITION;`

Your input layout only has 3 floats for that item. Not sure if it's the problem but it doesn't look quite right.

Comment: Input semantics cant be on these inputs? Mind warp. The float4 think is something I asked about before. Others say its for aligning the data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889619/understanding-shader-programming

Comment: SV_POSITION is the appropriate semantic for the output from the vertex shader and the input to the pixel shader. It's not right for the input to the vertex shader, just use your own name. POSITION will work fine, clearly it needs to be the same name in both the struct in the VS and in the input layout declaration. In your VS you are loading 4 floats into pos but only providing it with data for 3 in the input. I *think* it will still work as you'd expect as long as you only use .xyz elements in the shader though. Other than that not really sure how to help (